# Is there a way to use the old (tinymce3) userinterface with tinymce4?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor, rte, tinymce-4

I am pretty much used to Tinymce3.
The new tinymce version is not in beta anymore so it can be integrated into our CMS.

Problem here is that our customers won't be happy with the new user interface.
I am looking for an easy way to get the look of the old Tinymce3-UI work with Tinymce4.

Any suggestions?